# Read a S3 CSV file using Boto3 Session

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, amazon-s3, boto3

I am currently using boto3 client to read a S3 csv file in Python dataframe. Below is the code (not working properly, many columns are combined in one, instead of 40 columns my dataframe has 8 columns). Can someone please suggest alternate/better code to read using boto3 Session?

```
s3 = session.resource('s3')
obj = s3.Object(bucket_name=Buckets,key=filename)
response=obj.get()
data = response['Body'].read()
df = pd.read_fwf((io.BytesIO(data)) ,  delimiter=',', error_bad_lines=False,header=None)
print(df)
```

I was able to do it using boto3 client. I used below code (can I do something similar for boto3 session as well since this looks so clean and works fine):

```
response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=Bucket1, Key=filename)
books_df = pd.read_csv(response.get("Body"))
```

Comment: Using boto3 is the correct approach. You might also be interested in using the [smart-open · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/smart-open/) library, which allows you to use the `open()` command on S3 objects in the same way it is used on local files.

Comment: your first code is not working because you're using `read_fwf` instead of `read_csv`